# Window.open script manager is opening 2 pages

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a `btn_click` event firing a method that should open the link but instead it opens 2 tabs: a duplicate of the open page and the desired link.
this is in the `btn_click`.

```
Redirect_New_Tab("http://www.desiredlink.com");
```

and this is the method that it is calling.

```
private void Redirect_New_Tab(string url_To_Open)
{
    string modified_URL = "window.open('" + url_To_Open + "', '_blank');";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", modified_URL, true);
}
```

and the resault of this method is that there are now 3 tabs open. 2 duplicates of the original aspx page and a tab with the opened link.

is there anything I'm doing wrong or can do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just call `window.open` straight from `OnClientClick` event?

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="Server" OnClientClick="window.open('http://www.desiredlink.com')" />
```